# Dimension regularization "v.s." fractional diffusion equation in worldline representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization

This is a very speculative question...

Instead using dimensional regularization in QFT, for instance, $d = 4 - 2\epsilon$), one may imagine, thinking to the worldline representation of QFT (associated to the Schwinger representation of the propagator), (see for instance this paper of  [Strassler](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9205205)), staying in $4$ dimensions, but modifying the propagator (for instance, in the Schwinger representation of the scalar massless propagator, in position space, for each space-time coordinate $x$, we may consider using (formally)  $x^\alpha$, with $\alpha$ different of $2$, instead of $x^2$), this would correspond (possibly assuming euclideanization) to a (space-time) fractional diffusion equation (see this paper of [Mainardi and all](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0702419), and also the definition of [stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)- $\alpha$ is known as the stability parameter). A possible hint would be that [Mellin-Barnes representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral) are used both in the fractional diffusion material, and also in QFT.

If my question makes sense, are there concrete examples in the litterature of such a (speculative) alternative point of view?